# Compiling android tools for windows

Tags: android, windows, linux, sdk, cross-compiling

I have set up a 64 bit ubuntu env for compiling android tools (aapt, adb etc...), i'm now downloading the source code for 2.1.

I have compiled the env in the past with no problem, built emulator and stock version.
But it was all linux binaries (the sdk tools)

The more i think about it the less i understand,How i can build those tools for windows machine ? 
(ubuntu runs on virtual box on top of my hosting Server 2008 which is my work env).

I saw some posts related to minGW but as far as i know these are windows libraries that are meant to compile linux binaries on windows machine. I am looking for a  way to compile windows binaries on linux machine.

I must say it seems impossible since i'm not sure how the linker in linux will generate an exe file, ithought of taking the .o file and try to link them under windows (VS) but i'm not sure it will work, I'll have to find compatible dlls to the API's on linux.

How do goolge create a windows SDK?

Comment: found this somewhere on the web http://osdir.com/ml/android-platform/2009-02/msg00808.html i'll try the build script with minGW later on or cygwin and see if it works for me

Comment: i could be wrong... there is a mingw32 lib for linux and apparently there is make win_sdk under android, though the script for building windows seems like it can do it under cygwin as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well with the help of several posts and of  'inazaruk' i managed to find the command : `$ make -j PRODUCT-sdk-win_sdk showcommands dist`
it compiled and in ./out/host/ i had the windows binaries. pretty cool :-) i didn't need to take them out and recompile under windows.

Hopes this helps anyone else that needs to recompile the SDK tools.

Comment: it's third or forth time i answer my own questions, it's not like i like it, but i get no bloody answers :-?

Answer (score 0):

```
make -j8 win_sdk
```

also builds windows sdk.